# Does `Box` obscure trait bounds? Why can i assign `dyn FnOnce()` to `dyn Fn()` in this case?

Tags: rust

I'd like to have a struct, `Quox` which can optionally have each type of closure that there can be(`Fn`, `FnMut` and `FnOnce`) around. I typed it this way:

```rust
#[derive(Default, Debug)]
pub struct Quox<Tfn: Fn(&Person) + Sized, Tfnmut: FnMut(&mut Person) + Sized, Tfnonce: FnOnce(&Person) + Sized> {
    soft_closure: Option<Tfn>,
    mut_closure : Option<Tfnmut>,
    move_closure: Option<Tfnonce>,
}
```

Now, when instantiating it i do it via `Box` because Rust complains `` the trait Sized is not implemented for `dyn Fn()`rustcE0277 ``. (Maybe there is a better way or i misunderstand trait objects?):

```rust
pub fn main(){
    let mut qx = Quox::<Box<dyn Fn(&Person)>, Box<dyn FnMut(&mut Person)>, Box<dyn FnOnce(&Person)>> {
        move_closure: None,
        mut_closure : None,
        soft_closure: None,
    };
    ...

}
```

1. What really perplexes me further is when i create the corresponding types of closures -- why i can assign them willy-nilly to the fields inside `qx`:

```rust
pub fn main(){
    let mut qx = Quox::<Box<dyn Fn(&Person)>, Box<dyn FnMut(&mut Person)>, Box<dyn FnOnce(&Person)>> {
        move_closure: None,
        mut_closure : None,
        soft_closure: None,
    };


    let greeting  = "Hi. We are moving soon!".to_string();
    let clsr_move = move |p:&Person| println!("Hi, {}. {} says: {}", p.name, p.name, greeting);
    let only_a_ref_clsr = |p:&Person| println!("Hi, {}.",p.name );

 
    // qx.move_closure = Some(Box::new(clsr_move));        // expected
    // qx.soft_closure = Some(Box::new(only_a_ref_clsr));  // expected

    qx.soft_closure = Some(Box::new(clsr_move));           // Why is this valid???
    qx.move_closure = Some(Box::new(only_a_ref_clsr));     // Ok Fn is supertrait to FnOnce

}
```

Again, what's confusing is that i'm getting no error for trying to assign a (seemingly) `FnMut` to `Fn`.

---

2. Furthermore... why assigning the `Box` to an intermediary variable now throws error???

```rust
pub fn main(){
    let mut qx = Quox::<Box<dyn Fn(&Person)>, Box<dyn FnMut(&mut Person)>, Box<dyn FnOnce(&Person)>> {
        move_closure: None,
        mut_closure : None,
        soft_closure: None,
    };


    let greeting  = "Hi. We are moving soon!".to_string();
    let clsr_move = move |p:&Person| println!("Hi, {}. {} says: {}", p.name, p.name, greeting);
    let only_a_ref_clsr = |p:&Person| println!("Hi, {}.",p.name );

    let someboxmove = Some(Box::new(only_a_ref_clsr));
    qx.soft_closure = someboxmove;                         // Invalid. 

}
```

The error i'm getting is:

```bash
let someboxmove: Option<Box<|&Person| -> ()>>
Go to Option | Box | Person | Global

mismatched types
expected enum `Option<Box<dyn for<'r> Fn(&'r traitobjects::Person)>>`
   found enum `Option<Box<[closure@src/traitobjects.rs:49:27: 49:66]>>`rustcE0308
traitobjects.rs(49, 27): the found closure
traitobjects.rs(66, 5): expected due to the type of this binding
```

Comment: There are several things going on here, but most importantly your example 1 ("What really perplexes me") does not compile as stated. Can you double-check what the code you are using is?!

Comment: Your first question confuses me. There's no reason `clsr_move` can't be `Fn`. [This compiles](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=84412e5718c67ca52084610414962a41). Perhaps you are confused about the `move` keyword, but that is for moving variables *into* the closure, but what makes a closure strictly `FnOnce` is if variables are moved *out*.

Comment: @user2722968 indeed! Forgot the `&mut Person`, sorry. The gist for the 1st example is that i'm getting _no_ error though. that's what's confusing.

Comment: @kmdreko that's the answer. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Boiling down your first question:

```
let greeting  = "Hi. We are moving soon!".to_string();
let clsr_move = move |p:&Person| println!("Hi, {}. {} says: {}", p.name, p.name, greeting);

let soft_closure: Box<dyn Fn(&Person)> = Some(Box::new(clsr_move));
```

There's no reason that `clsr_move` can't be `Fn`. The `move` is for telling the compiler to move all captures *into* the closure, but what makes a closure strictly `FnOnce` is if variables were moved *out* of the closure. This closure can obviously be called again and again.

---

Your second problem is simply a side-effect of Rust's type inference. If the type that `Box::new()` should create is not immediately clear from the expression, then it will pick the type that was given to it; in the latter case the anonymous type of the closure. In the former, it can see that it is going to be assigned to something expecting a `Box<dyn ...>` and can preemptively coerce the type. So its simply the case that the inference algorithm does not look far enough ahead.

It also can't implicitly coerce a `Option<Box<T>>` into a `Option<Box<dyn Trait>>`. It could coerce a `Box<T>` into a `Box<dyn Trait>`, but since these have different sizes and layouts it doesn't extend as a generic parameter for `Option`